# Local files are innaccessible from an external url using PhoneGap on Android

Tags: android, cordova

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/www/images/image.png" style="border: black dashed 2px"/>
```

This line of code works as expected on a local html file.

However when you open an external url inside the app. (For example http://www.example.com/mobile/) The same line of code doesn't show an image.

To be clear, I am trying to access local files from an external url, because there are some JS files that are huge and It will be a waste of bandwidth to download them externally.

Comment: which version of phonegap you are using??

Comment: I need something similar. After loading an external page, I need to return to the local `index.html`. No luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote site will never be able to load an image from the file:// protocol.

Comment: why? - Is there a specification that enforce this?

Comment: I don't know about a specification but that is what webkit decided. It kinda a good idea when you think about it though.

Answer (score 1):

As @simon said u wont be able to load local assests on external url.. At best u can use loadDataWithBaseURL which will load your html with imgs/css/js from local assets folders 
something like this

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/", html, 
                        "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```