# How to Access asset resources from server on phonegap

Tags: android, ios, css, windows, cordova

I am on developing cross platform phonegap application.Here i am loading a webpage which is hosted in server.
i have done it by changing my loadUrl("***.***..*/server/index.html");

Then I want to know is there any way to load required css/image files from assets folder on phonegap.Like what we are doing when all files are reside in www folder of phonegap.

I have tried this 
but it got error, local resource cannot be accessible.
And I am asking is there any possible way to do so???

I am once more mentioning that i am trying for a cross platform application.

Thanks in advance for your valuable reply...

Comment: posibly you have not enebled cors http://stackoverflow.com/a/26402667/3556874

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i think cors is for accessing resources from other domain,but i am actually trying to access resource from asset folder.

Comment: but you said your web page is on server right?

Comment: yes,web page is on the server.The html content reside on the server and i want to load css+images for that webpage from my asset folder.Is there any way to do so??

Comment: Is there any other way to speed up my phonegap application??

Comment: what you mean by speed up

Comment: I am trying to access local asset resources on the server html page for smooth and quick rendering of webpage without having a high data transfer on the application (due to loading image and css). Is there any alternative solution to achieve this??

Comment: Ok i get your question.. let me write a short answer

Answer (score 0):

So what I understand from your question is:

> 1. you access a html page from server
> 2. you want that page to use local resources such as image.

So answer to this question is simply [**No**, you cant do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915668/3556874).

---

but yes, you can change your approach a little bit, and still download html from server and use local images from assets.

let the page be on the app itself, and just load the html from the server using `ajax`.

Steps:

1) index.html will reside within the app

2) download html from server using ajax call
  ex:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourserver.com/getHtml",
        dataType: "html", // set the datatype to html
        success: function (data) {
            // append the data here to page
        }

    });
});
```

Now, **that you have loaded the html for the page from server, still your page is local** So you are now able to load local assets like images into your webpage like you normally do from `www` folder.